# IntelliJ on macOS, how do I jump to previously defined bookmark?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

On IntelliJ mac, is there a way to add a bookmark on the code where we can jump to that piece of code with a shortcut

I can add a bookmark by using F11 or command F11 and give it a number but is there then a shortcut I can use say if i'm somewhere else in that file but want to jump to the bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHIFT-F11` is the thing you are looking for. Alternatively:
Navigate/Bookmarks/Show Bookmarks